# Generation of ssh keygen in Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, ssh

I've just bought a machine with Chrome OS installed. I need to connect via ssh to a remote server, which needs to have my generated keygen to grant me any access to it. I am following the instructions `Esc + Refresh (F3) + Power button` in order to go to the `Developer mode`, but it just closes my login session and does nothing but spending my time. Command `ssh-keygen` does not exist in `chrosh`.

Would you help me to find out a solution?

Answer (score 4):

First taking look at https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/tips-and-tricks: Private keys **have to be generated on a different computer** and copied to the File Shelf of the Chromebook via SD Card.

Now after you have generated your key and copied it to SD card, take a look at [this page](http://andrew.jorgensenfamily.us/2013/01/chromeos-ssh-keys/) :

```
Download your key to the Downloads directory. I keep an encrypted copy of my key in Google Drive.
Press Ctrl-Alt-T to open a terminal tab.
At the crosh> prompt, type the following:
    ssh
    user <your-user-name>
    host <your-host-name>
    key <your-key-filename> (not the full path)
    connect
```

Comment: No. I must create a key for my ChromeOS, since I want to connect to my server, which requires a known client via key generated in the client computer.

Comment: I don't think so, IMHO you can as well generate the key elsewhere. Anyway, the the crosh shell doesn't have any command for creating a key

Comment: indeed, generating it elsewhere and using it with this worked perfectly for me! https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/FAQ.md#Can-I-connect-using-a-public-key-pair-or-certificate no need for root/devmode

Comment: Public and private keys are portable and don't need to be generated per machine, but they should pretty much ALWAYS be protected with a passphrase and treated like the password to your bank account because the private key is quite literally the "key to the kingdom". Another option is to get a smartcard that can provide GPG/PIV functionality that can be used as an SSH private key but the private key is stored securely on the card and can't be extracted without physical access and very expensive equipment. Yubikey, Nitrokey, and Solokeys all have GPG functionality, and Yubikey also has PIV.

Answer (score 3):

Aware this post hasn't been posted on for over a year however I think this may work:

1. Install [Chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew#installation)
2. Now install libssh2 (think this package is for generating) by typing in `crew install libssh2`

NOTE: You need to have [dev mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/) enabled.
NOTE 2: I'm posting this for others who may want to do this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106243/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-generation-of-ssh-keygen-in-chrome-os).

Answer (score 3):

The 2020 answer to this question is that most Chromebooks have the ability to run Linux apps via Crostini.

You can install the Linux apps feature and launch the Terminal application which gives you a Debian Linux "container" where you can install the `ssh-client` package using `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ssh-client` or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ssh-client` to get the `ssh-keygen` tool and have the ability to generate an RSA or ECDSA key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`.

Note that if using RSA you'll want to ensure you are using 4096 bits as the 1024 and 2048 bit versions are considered potentially unsafe as there have been some advances in cryptography that allow reversing a public key to a private key using cloud services or access to a large compute cluster and while that is probably limited currently to targets of nation-state attacks, within a few years that may become far more feasible on consumer hardware or trivially inexpensive in the cloud.

Comment: Crostini is not as battery efficient as using the Chrome Secure Shell App...

Comment: Not for long term running, but you only need ssh-keygen, then you copy the files out to ChromeOS and use them with Secure Shell. Or better yet buy a Yubikey and use a GPG key for SSH and many other things.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to a machine with ssh-keygen or want to generate the key completely locally, you can use [this stand-alone page](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matvore/220f7e61f2529c2d6e3033c3eb5fc16d/raw/a46602de52a5b704e86cc725e15d72e0dc7c9a8f/js-keygen.html) [1] which is a modified version of https://js-keygen.surge.sh/ but with the config options not broken and the site downloadable as a single file. It does not send the keys anywhere or save them in the cloud.

To generate an SSH keypair, you can click "Generate" with the default options and then click "Save" for each key of the pair.

[1] Just in case, I have mirrored this page here: https://scito.surge.sh/js-keygen.html

Comment: beside my thanks, i'd warn the user that some extensions might prevent the browser from running this. you might disable extensions on this page and refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run in developer mode you can use [this](https://github.com/google/chrome-ssh-agent) extension.

There is some risk in this process as keys are synced in chrome, but it's useful for development in a pinch.

Comment: That extension doesn't have an option to generate a new key. You have to paste in a PEM-formatted key to add one to the agent.